# sql 2000 and sql 2005 instances on same server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

How to install sql server 2000 and sql server 2005 on same server

Answer (score 2):

Just install them: one has to be [named instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165614%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

It is as easy as that

Answer (score 1):

have a look on:

http://geekswithblogs.net/tmoore/archive/2005/11/13/59971.aspx

http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/tip/Installing-SQL-Server-2005-on-a-SQL-2000-machine